# Node.js: variable to act as nested element name for an object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, node.js-stream, node.js-client

Here is my object:

```
    obj = {
      "FirstName": "Fawad",
      "LastName": "Surosh",
      "Education": {"University": "ABC", "Year": "2012"}
    }
```

Here is my node.js code:

```
var nodeName = 'Education.Year';
obj.nodeName; //this should return the value of Year which is '2012'
```

Is there any way for implementing this solution? It is because my nodeName is extracted from db table and is not specific.

Comment: See [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key) as well as [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split `nodeName` by `.` and for each piece navigate the object.

```
var result;
result = obj['Education'];
result = obj['Year'];

console.log(result); // 2012
```

Example:

```js
var obj = {
  "FirstName": "Fawad",
  "LastName": "Surosh",
  "Education": {"University": "ABC", "Year": "2012"}
};

var nodeName = 'Education.Year';

var result = nodeName.split('.').reduce((a, b) => {
  a = a[b];
  return a;
}, obj);

document.getElementById('result').value = result;
```

```html
<input id='result' type='text' />
```